# If a system restore restores the registry to how it was before, then how come a trial version of a program does not reset?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, system-restore, licensing

I do the following in the given order:

1. Create a system restore point. There is a note of what the registry looks like
2. Download a program which has a trial of X days
3. When that trial runs out, use system restore to return to the previous point **before** the program installation

After these steps, the trial for the program does **not** reset, even though the registry returned to how it was before. Why is this?

Comment: Probably because MS and vendors realized people would try and cheat the system, and created an area that is protected that is not reset.  It may not even be in the registry as MS might have hidden storage of this info.

Comment: @thebuddha  Think about this for a moment: You've come to a web site devoted to developers and asked, in essence, "How do I cheat a developer?"  That's NOT what the Buddha would do.

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of ways a trial application could do this, the registry being only one. Let us assume it does use the registry. System Restore does not restore the entire registry but only portions of it. All the application has to do is store some obscure value in some unsuspected location. Someone could be looking at it and never recognize it for what it was. If the application installer found this value it would know the application had been previously installed.

One such location would be the profile of one of the built in accounts. This would not be touched by System Restore and is easily accessed. Developers are aware of how System Restore works and would use a location it would not reverse. And developers tend to be very resourceful. Any competent developer could think of several other methods in little time. Obviously none of this would be documented.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this will help, it was my first thought. Export the entire Registry at the point before the program installation.

Win+R\regedit\File\Export(this opens a save as dialog in 'Documents.')\FileName\save.
I use FullReg(todaysDate).reg > FullReg090217.reg as the filename.

Make sure that in the lower portion of the dialog box,Export range, the button for All is selected.

Comment: This is just restating the OP's original question.